# lbfgs solver in sklearn logistic regression: how do I set stopping criteria?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, solver

I am using LogisticRegression in sklearn.linear_model, below:

```
LR = linear_model.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', solver='lbfgs', C=500.0, max_iter=9000, verbose=1, random_state=None, tol=1e-8)
LR.fit(X, y, sample_weight=w)
```

However, when I look at the iteration output, I have reasons to believe that the lbfgs solver terminated prematurely (see the |Projg| below).  Here's the console print from lbfgs:

```
RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE
           * * *
Machine precision = 2.220D-16
 N =          133     M =           10
At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds
At iterate    0    f=  9.89761D+08    |proj g|=  4.12846D+13
At iterate   50    f=  2.64178D+07    |proj g|=  1.86171D+10
At iterate  100    f=  2.15258D+07    |proj g|=  4.07193D+10
... 
At iterate 3100    f=  1.32850D+07    |proj g|=  1.93364D+08
At iterate 3150    f=  1.32844D+07    |proj g|=  5.57729D+09
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:   42.0s finished
           * * *
Tit   = total number of iterations
Tnf   = total number of function evaluations
Tnint = total number of segments explored during Cauchy searches
Skip  = number of BFGS updates skipped
Nact  = number of active bounds at final generalized Cauchy point
Projg = norm of the final projected gradient
F     = final function value
           * * *
   N    Tit     Tnf  Tnint  Skip  Nact     Projg        F
  133   3175   3923      1     0     0   1.915D+07   1.328D+07
  F =   13283607.832458526     
CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH             
 Cauchy                time 0.000E+00 seconds.
 Subspace minimization time 0.000E+00 seconds.
 Line search           time 0.000E+00 seconds.
 Total User time 0.000E+00 seconds.
```

My question is: How to I set the stopping criteria, like the _FACTR above, or ESPMCH above, or Projg, so that lbfgs does not terminate prematurely?

Comment: Also, it appears that the step size used by lbfgs solver is too small -- how do I specify the step size?

Comment: Have you seen https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/167199

Comment: @Ian Quah:  Thanks!